# Android Studio cannot define my XML file

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created Layout files , and they are containe an elements which have id's , the problem is Android Studio  is not define it ! , for example , if I have a xml file called my.xml , which is located in the Layout , and when I write R.layout.my , android studio tells me that this file is not exist ! but if you look to the project file , you will see that my.xml , is located there. I have tried to make new project , but it's give me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is in folder name. Probably you should rename "Layout" folder to "layout". Also you should check that your layout folder are in "res" folder.

Comment: it named "layout" , and it's located in the "res" folder , the problem is not in the layout only , the problem is also in id and main